# Difference between $ and g_ in vim?

Tags: vim

I was trying to learn some new neat shortcuts in vim and I discovered g_. According to 
http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/

```
$  → go to the end of line
g_ → go to the last non-blank character of line
```

When would I use g_ instead of $?

Comment: ...when you want to go to the last non-blank character in the line, in case the line has trailing spaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the most important difference is simply stated in the help files:

```
:h $
In Visual mode the cursor goes to just after the last character in the line.
```

So if you do <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> it deletes including "after the last character" which is the newline so it will bring the line below it up to the current one. But if you do <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g_</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> it will keep the newline.

I actually didn't know about `g_`, seems useful.

**Edit** Since this answer gets upvotes, I have since used `g_` (and its reverse, `_`) to make a mapping that yanks / deletes the current line excluding leading/trailing whitespace and excluding linebreaks:

```
" delete/yank line, but only whitespace-trimmed version
nnoremap <Leader>dd _yg_"_dd
nnoremap <Leader>yy _yg_
```

Answer (score 12):

`g_` is AWESOME when you're yanking text to paste somewhere you don't want the line break included -- like the command line where it will then automatically run the command.

Comment: is there an easier way without plugins? I feel like I'm typing an essay to copy and paste: `"*yg_` read "into my system register, yank, until the end of the line without the newline", am I missing something? I watched this youtube video that mentions OSC 52 https://youtu.be/E-ZbrtoSuzw?t=2816 seems like it might have a way to link yank with system clipboard